# Get last modified file time dynamically

Tags: php, filemtime

I've made a few unsuccessful attempts. I want to get the last modified file time, by current file - i.e. the file currently being viewed. The following code works for the employer.es.php file, but I reuse this in other files unless I keep changing the file names.

```
    <?php
    // make var from file name
    $last_modified = filemtime("employer.es.php");
    // print date
    echo "Information last modified on " . date("m/d/Y", $last_modified);
    ?>
```

So instead of having to type the files name into each file, I want it to use the current file.
Hope I'm making sense :/
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__FILE__` [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) should help you out here.

`$last_modified = filemtime(__FILE__);`

Comment: Also, if you are performing multiple filesystem operations on the script during its execution (perhaps prior to `filemtime()`), I strongly recommend implementing [clearstatcache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).

Comment: Ugh. I tried that, but didn't have the correct syntax. Works now! And thanks very much for the recommendation - I'll check it out.